# I'm newbie with pyautogui and I have a problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

```
import pyautogui as gui
import time

time.sleep(2)

def click(x,y):
    gui.click((x,y))
    time.sleep(0.1) 
    
mino =  gui.locateOnScreen("mino1.png",region=(436,282, 150, 70))
life =  gui.locateOnScreen("vidabaixa.png",region=(0,0, 300, 300))
if mino != None:
    click (471,315)
if life != None:
    click (88, 547)
    click (88, 547)
```

The pngs are on screen, and the script do nothing.
And it didn't show any error, just nothing.

Comment: Please describe the question in the title. This will help people scrolling through multiple questions understand what you are asking without having to click inside.

Comment: The code is doing nothing probably because pyautogui is finding the 100% exact images on screen (if even a single pixel is different pyautogui will not find it), you could try adding the confidence keyword to lower the accuracy and see if that works: `life =  gui.locateOnScreen("vidabaixa.png",region=(0,0, 300, 300, confidence=0.8))`